# Updating cell using input

Tags: microsoft-excel

On one of my reports, I have to enter in several order numbers.  The order numbers all start with the same thing, but end in different numbers. example: "XXX-XXXXX-12345-..." where the "..." represents the identifying number.

Is there a way to change what the cell shows by entering in the identifying number only?  So I just want to be able to enter in "9876" and it will automatically print "XXX-XXXXX-12345-9876."

Answer (score 3):

To display it in the same cell, you can set a Custom Format.  Use the string, including quotes:

```
"XXX-XXXXX-12345-"0000
```

Note that Excel won't read this whole string if you reference the cell somewhere else.  If you type `9876`, you will see `XXX-XXXXX-12345-9876`.  If you use a formula to copy that order number, it will only copy the `9876` that you typed.

---

Alternatively, you can use a formula if you want the results in a different cell.  Assuming you type your `9876` in cell A1:

```
="XXX-XXXXX-12345-"&A1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using formulas, with the input numbers in coll b, you can just put in cell A1 
       ***="XXX-XXXX-12345-" & b1*** and drag the formula as far down as you need. Once you've entered all your numbers you can copy-paste value only and discard col. b.